# What are the languages packs and subtitle languages in Diablo 3 on windows

Tags: diablo-iii, windows

What language packs and subtitle languages does Diablo 3 have on windows from battle.net?

I've searched around but not been able to find the list.

I found this post from 2013 about the playstation version
https://eu.battle.net/forums/en/d3/topic/8114051709#post-4

> Q: What languages will the game be available in?
>   A: Both console versions of Diablo III will be fully localized in English, German, French, European and Latin American Spanish, Russian, Italian, Polish, and Brazilian Portuguese.

What are the languages for windows?

Answer (score 2):

Obtained from battle launcher options for text/spoken language droplist.

- English
- Spanish (AL) - Latin America
- Portuguese - (Brazil and Portugal)
- French
- German
- Italian
- Russian
- Polish
- Chinese
- Korean

[image: Screen capture of the Game Settings screen on the Settings dialog of the Blizzard Launcher, showing the open Text & Spoken Language dropdown and several of the options within it]

Comment: I dont have enough space to install it, please let me know
is this one in the list? 日本語

Comment: I think Asian languages are Korean and Chinese - see https://translate.google.com/#en/ko/Korean and https://translate.google.com/#zh-CN/en/%E6%BC%A2%E8%AA%9E%E4%B8%AD%E6%96%87 . I'm not expert though, so I didn't propose it as edit

Comment: I tried a few translate apparently I missed korea.